# Using Variable When Declaring Constructors

Tags: c++

I'm following a tutorial and I have this line:

```
Human(const std::string & name) : nameC(name) { }
```

My question

- Here what does & (ampersand) do?
- What does nameC(name) do? nameC is a variable itself, isn't it?

Comment: The `&` in this context means `name` is a reference to a `std::string` object. `nameC(name)` is in the constructor's *member intialization list*, so it is initializing the `nameC` class member with the value of `name`. This stuff is covered in any decent C++ book/tutorial, please do some research before asking questions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the comment. I've found lots of sources about oop in c++ however I'm too lazy to read hundreds of pages on a computer. I'm following this tutorial https://www.codeproject.com/articles/835135/object-oriented-programming-with-cplusplus

Comment: What tutorial are you following? Does it not explain these things?

Comment: Don't use online tutorials for C++. Those are generally garbage. Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539) instead.

Comment: I know. That's what I'm plannign to do :)